# Send video as fps from node.js to react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, socket.io, video-streaming

How to send a video as frames per second example 30fps via socket.io connection from node.js to react. And how to stream it in the react frontend.

From the backend the video should send to client as frames via socket connection and play it in the react.

```
      const frameRate = 30;
     ffmpeg(videoFilePath)
     .outputOptions('-vf',`fps=${frameRate}`)
     .on("error",(err)=>{
      console.error('Error in coverting into frames',err.message);
     })
     .on("end",()=>{
      console.log("video processing Finished")
     })
     .on('data',(chunk)=>{
      console.log("chunk",chunk)
      const frameFilePath = path.join(framesFolderPath, `${framePrefix}${frameIndex}.jpg`);
      fs.writeFileSync(frameFilePath, chunk);
      const frameData = fs.readFileSync(frameFilePath);
      console.log("frameData",frameData)
      socket.emit('frame', frameData);
      frameIndex++;
     })
```

tried this but frames are not getting consoled

Comment: it is urgent please help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ```
framesFolderPath D:\videoPlayer\server\public\frames
tempFolderPath D:\videoPlayer\server\public\temp
videoFilePath D:\videoPlayer\server\public\temp\Aximmetry 1123.mp4
```
paths are correct and there is no error showing